# New to c# need to understand How can I Fix this error? "Possible null reference return" I've tried every option in visual studio and nothing fixed it

Tags: c#

Learning C# should this be fixed or left alone? I can't seem to find an answer that works every action in VS didn't resolve the issue answer's I found online I either didn't understand or failed as well. Why I am asking here.

```
`
```

```
    public class AdventureService : IAdventureService
    {
        public Adventure GetInitialAdventure() 
        {
            var basePath = $"   {AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory}Adventures";
            var initialAdventure = new Adventure();

            if (File.Exists($"{basePath}\\initial.json"))
            {
                var directory = new DirectoryInfo(basePath);
                var initialJsonFile =    directory.GetFiles("initial.json");

                using (StreamReader fi =   File.OpenText(initialJsonFile[0].FullName))
                {
                    initialAdventure = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Adventure>(fi.ReadToEnd());
                }
            }

            return initialAdventure;
        }
```

`

Comment: What happens if `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` returns null?

Comment: that's what I am trying to figure out why I am asking here I am baffled

Comment: If `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` returns null then the function returns null. If you want to avoid that assign the result to a different variable and if the result is not null assign it to `initialAdventure`.

Comment: @Syziel Ninja’s question was rhetorical. `DeserializeObject` returns `T?` - not `T` because your input JSON _could_ contain just “`null`“. You need to add your own not-null assertion.

Comment: I have no idea how to do a not-null assertion I'm still learning C# this is the first time I've seen this error

Answer (score 0):

You need to decide what the method will do if the deserialize call returns null.

One option is for the method to return null, in which case you just need to change the return type:

```
public Adventure? GetInitialAdventure() 
{
    //Etc.
```

If you prefer that the method never return null, you could change the return statement so that it replaces a null with a new `Adventure`.

```
    //Rest of method up here
    return initialAdventure ?? new Adventure();
}
```

There are maybe other options as well but these are the basics.